# How do I maximize the function $f(x,y)=g(x,y)-ax-by$ given non-negativity and inequality constraints in the description?

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

If

$$f(x,y)=g(x,y)-ax-by,$$
$$x,y,a,b \ge 0,$$
$$ax+by\le m$$
and $$\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}\gt 0$$
$$\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}\gt0$$
$$\frac {\partial ^2g(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\lt 0$$
$$\frac {\partial ^2g(x,y)}{\partial y^2} \lt 0$$

For what values of $x,y$ (preferably as an expression of a,b, and m, or as a differential equation), is the value of $f$ maximum? What is the maximum value?

Comment: Try with $\nabla f=0$ for the open set, and use Lagrange multipliers for the closed one

Comment: Thank you very much, and I'm really very sorry that I updated the question info as I'm new to the formatting and got a bit confused , missing parts of the question itself focussing excessively on the formatting!

Comment: Do we know anything about $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$?

Comment: $\frac {\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y} $ .... but you may take $\frac {\partial ^2g}{\partial x\partial y}\gt0$, similarly $\frac {\partial ^2g}{\partial y\partial x}\gt0$